# Navigating pages in options dialog (Visual Studio Extension)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, wfp

**Visual Studio Extension**

I have a custom page that is in options dialog. I want to navigate to another page (via a link) in the same instance of that dialog. How would i go around to do so?

I am using `MenuCommandService` to open invoke command that opens Options page. I can do the same for another page, but that opens a new instance of options dialog

Thanks

Comment: What's the specific page? Is it also part of your extension, maybe you can get some help from [this thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/cc826083%28v%3dvs.120%29#to-display-a-custom-options-page).

Comment: No, it is the default page that comes with Visual Studio (under Environment Category). That is what i am doing right now (via GUID and MenuCommandService), but it opens a new options dialog every time. I would hope it'll use already opened instance of dialog and show the page in it

Comment: Apart from MenuCommandService, I haven't found any other api described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/visual-studio-sdk?view=vs-2019) which can work to open options dialog... Maybe you can check the document for the useful info.

Comment: I thought it might not be possible. But i was hoping that someone somewhere knows a workaround. Anyways, thanks for the links Lance

Comment: You're welcome. Edited the tags to make more members to see this issue..